# Can I get my php page to redirect a custom html page with error messages

Tags: php, validation, redirect, error-handling

I have a non-ajax PHP form validation and mail sent page. When the mail is sent or there are validations errors, the page redirect to a another blank page with the echoed success or failure messages. Can this redirect with the messages be done on a custom-designed page (i.e., one that has a header, footer, menu, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the message state in a `$_SESSION` to remember the status (e.g. error, success, etc). This way, you can ensure that the success/error message page is only accessed once, by deleting the `$_SESSION` again.
For redirecting, use

```
header("Location: path/to/your/html/page");
```

In the end, your code could look like this:

page1.php

```
session_start();

if(form submitted){
    if(no errors){
        $_SESSION['status'] = 0;    // 0 for no error
    }else{
        $_SESSION['status'] = 1;    // 1 for some other error. Extend it as you prefer
    }

    // Redirect to second page with header, body, footer,etc.
    header("Location: page2.php");
}
```

page2.php

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['status']){
    header("Location: /");    // redirect if no status has been set yet
}

// if we reach this line, we have a status and the user should be able
// to read it once

if($_SESSION['status'] == 0){
     print "Hey nice, no errors!";
}else{
     print "Oh no, something went wrong!";
}

// delete session at the end
unset($_SESSION['status']);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved lots of hours trying to resolve this issue.